# How to assign a datatemplate to textbox wpf

Tags: wpf, textbox

TextBox is supposed to show masked dollar amount for certain access privileges. I created a converter class(inheriting from IValueConverter)  to handle masking by implementing the convert method.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
                  CultureInfo culture)
```

The third parameter is passed true if masking is needed else false.

Called like this:

```
CurrencyCOnverter converter = new CurrencyConverter();

this._textbox1.Text = converter.Convert(Amount, typeof(string), !this.IsSuperUser,
                          CurrentCulture).ToString();
```

I have about 12 textboxes on UI. Instead of doing this at 12 places, I defined DataTemplates in Resource dictionary which looks like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MaskNormalBackgroundTbx">

 <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"
            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
            Text="{Binding "Amount" 
                   Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, 
                   ConverterParameter=true}" />    
</DataTemplate>

 <DataTemplate x:Key="NoMaskNormalBackgroundTbx">

 <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
            Text="{Binding "Amount" 
                   Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, 
                   ConverterParameter=false}" />    
 </DataTemplate>
```

My Question: Is there a way I can assign this template to textbox by creating a custom textbox just like we assign data templates for ListBox?

Thanks,

Megan.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a ContentControl to display your DataTemplate. Another idea, which I prefer in this case, is to use styles. Below code shows hot to do both.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:Test"
    Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>

        <Test:CurrencyDisplayConverter x:Key="CurrencyDisplayConverter" />

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MaskNormalBackgroundTbxDT">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"  
            Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="MaskNormalBackgroundTbxStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="WrapWithOverflow" />
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=Amount, Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>

        <ContentControl
            Content="{Binding Path=Amount}" 
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MaskNormalBackgroundTbxDT}" />

        <TextBlock 
            Style="{StaticResource MaskNormalBackgroundTbxStyle}" />

    </StackPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Wallstreet Programmer,
Thanks for your response. I already have a custom textbox with label and other customized control templates and properties in place. I would add onto that rather than replacing the textbox control itself. Please let me know if you have any ideas on how to make it work with a textbox control.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a style then like in above sample (MaskNormalBackgroundTbxStyle)

Comment: Inserted this trigger inside the style of custom textbox:

    <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, ConverterParameter=true}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Tag" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CurrencyDisplayConverter}, ConverterParameter=false}"/>
            </Trigger> 
Not sure why, text in textbox is never masked.