# Databinding issue with textbox and accessors

Tags: wpf, data-binding, object, binding, accessor

I am wondering what am I missing? The binding is not displaying at all in the textbox. These are my codes:

XAML Namespace:

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:mySystem.Workspace"
```

DataContext and Resources:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <c:Parameter x:Key="mySource"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource mySource}" />
        </Canvas.DataContext>
```

Textbox:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" Width="159" Height="26" Canvas.Left="36" Canvas.Top="47">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="JobKey" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
            </TextBox.Text>
```

The class:

```
namespace mySystem.Workspace
{
  public class Parameter : Object  
  {
```

The accessors:

```
 public BasePar JobKey
 {
   get { return jobKey; }
   set { jobKey = value; }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does the `BasePar` implementation look like? Have a look in the Debug Output window to see if you have a line like this:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 1 : Cannot create default converter to perform 'two-way' conversions between types 'WpfApplication1.BasePar' and 'System.String'. Consider using Converter property of Binding. BindingExpression:Path=JobKey; DataItem='Parameter' (HashCode=14209755); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='TextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')`

This is telling you that you are trying to bind to the property, but WPF cannot create a 2-way binding, because it cannot convert the text (you type into the TextBox) into a 'BasePar' object.

As per David's suggestion, you could bind to a primitive string type, or alternately (as per the warning message above) you could add a `Converter` to the binding to convert a string into a `BasePar`.

Comment: Yes, I can see the message. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of odd things here but the most obvious one that will get you working is that the Binding Path is case sensitive.

Change your binding to:

```
<Binding Path="JobKey" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
```

This should get the binding working.

I'm also not sure what type BasePar is, or is meant to be, but unless you are doing something clever intentionally, just make it a standard type like string.

You should also probably not use the namespace `System.Workspace`, but something related to your own project.

---

After your response, the only thing I can guess that the BasePar object is intended for, is to be used within a DataTemplate, on an ItemsControl say. DataTemplates have the behaviour that when they do not know how to render an Object they will fall back the the Object's .ToString() method.

Now, in my comment I said that I don't think the `TextBox` can have a DataTemplate, and I believe this is true *however* I did find a trick at [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167473/how-to-assign-a-datatemplate-to-textbox-wpf) which templates a content control and a textblock instead. The code is below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Workspace"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <c:Parameter x:Key="mySource"/>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.DataContext>
            <Binding Source="{StaticResource mySource}" />
        </Canvas.DataContext>

        <ContentControl            
           Content="{Binding Path=JobKey}"             
           ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyDataTemplate}" />
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

I don't have time right now to get the TextBox working - don't even know if it is possible, given my first few tries. However, this might help get you where you need to go.

But still - if I was me I'd just use simple binding to standard objects. I can't see the benefit of the BasePar class in this scenario.

Comment: I've updated my code to mySystem.Workspace and "JobKey" for binding path. - Still not working. BasePar is a class consisting for handling different types -string, doubles, integers. One expert created this based loosly on MVVM model and I'm trying to do the UI to the class that he has created.

Comment: @Ben I just tried this using almost exactly as you have with the only difference being JobKey was as type string. I've never tried to use a class like you are doing for binding. What happens if you try the binding with that property returning string?

Comment: @Ben Just googled and looks like you can do something like Text="{Binding PropObj1.prop1}" could you include the code of BasePar so we can see how it was intended to be used?

Comment: @Ben I think you need to check with the person who made that class. The only thing I can think that that class is intended for is to use when in a DataTemplate, which has the behaviour that when an Object type is not recognised, it uses the Object's .ToString() as far as I know TextBox cannot be DataTemplated, and I don't think this is ever going to work. I could be wrong, though I still think that this whole approach is too complicated, I'd just use a ViewModel that returns standard types instead.

Comment: @David Thanks for your help. It IS complicated and I will check with him. At least I could narrow the issue down to the class, thanks!

Comment: @Ben I've just updated with my latest research. Hope this helps lead you to a solution!

Comment: Much thanks! I'm going to stick with standard objects for now and try using a convertor when there's time.

Answer (score 1):

you need to make jobkey a DependencyProperty by deriving it from [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx) or derive your class from [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and add all the notify code, etc.

if you do not do this, then you will not receive update notifications and your bindings wont work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this is new to me and I will have to readup. I hope it is pointing me to right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> Path="jobKey"

You need to bind to the property not the field, i.e. make that upper-case. Also: To debug bindings check the Output-window in Visiual Studio.