# WPF Binding Object to Textbox and use DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Hallo I have some problems with my new WPF-Project.
I have a ListView with different Objects. When the user selects an object the "details" also the properties of this object are in the Textbox beside the listview.

Select object --> object goes to textbox --> textbox present object with a Data Template

In my test Project I fixed it with a second listview.

```
private void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(listView.SelectedItem is Entity)
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        listView1.Items.Add(listView.SelectedItem);
    }
}
```

Data Template for the textbox, in this example i used it for the second listView

```
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Entity}">
   <TextBox Text="{Binding A1}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

[A Screenshot from my test project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqQah.png)

I want to solve the problem like in this screenshot, but without a listview because i need to copy the properties and the focus from the listview ist annoying

Anybody knows a solution?

Greetings

Comment: **I want to solve the problem like in this screenshot,...** Which problem? 
Be more precise, it's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to have all entries in one list and when you click at one item you want to show all properties with value in another list or table?

Comment: I want to show the properties in a textbox. For each Object Type the textbox should have a Data Template. At the screenshot i used a listview but i want to use a textbox instead.

Comment: For displaying the Properties you could add a TextBox and bind directly to the SelectedItem of the ListView. (<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=listView, Path=SelectedItem.A1}"/>)

Comment: @OneByT Have a look at my answer.

Comment: Have a look at this post. Seems to be the same problem:[How to assign a datatemplate to textbox wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167473/how-to-assign-a-datatemplate-to-textbox-wpf?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any code behind for this.
Just set the `Name` property of your `ListView`; for example like this

```
<ListView x:Name="MyItems"
```

And then add a `TextBox` for each property you want to show when selection changed like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=MyItems, Path=SelectedItem.Prop1}"/>
```

`Prop1` is the name of the property you want to show.

**Edit**
When you have different kinds of objects in your list and you want to show the properties in another way for the different types you can use a `ContentControl` for this.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding ElementName=MyItems, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ObjectOne}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ObjectTwo}">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop1}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop2}"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Prop3}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

The `ContentControl` will show the first `DataTemplate` when you select an item of type `ObjectOne` and the second `DataTemplate` when you select an item of type `ObjectTwo`.

Hope that's what you wanted ;)

Comment: The problem is that i dont the know the objects. Thats the reason why i want to use Data Templates... So you can define for each object type a specific Data Template. If you select a item it will be mapped to the right object type and then give it to a control which is presenting the object with the specific Data Template you know?

Comment: @OneByT ok, can give you an answer tomorrow if still needed. Just left my pc and it's too much for writing with my mobile

Comment: Would be nice! Trank you !

Comment: It works ! Thats the solution i looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom TextBox which can reflect on property and load the Text as you need. Use that custom textbox and bind the object to it.

Example:

```
public class PropertyViewerTextBox : TextBox
{
    public object Item
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public PropertyViewerTextBox()
    {
        this.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        this.AcceptsReturn = true;
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Item.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(object), typeof(PropertyViewerTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemChanged));

    public static void OnItemChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textbox = sender as PropertyViewerTextBox;
        if (null == e.NewValue)
        {
            textbox.Text = string.Empty;
            return;
        }

        var props = e.NewValue.GetType().GetProperties();
        var text = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var prop in props)
        {
            text.AppendFormat("{0}{1}", prop.Name, Environment.NewLine);
        }

        textbox.Text = text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Once you have this custom textbox created, change your data template and use the custom textbox, bind to Item property. It will display all the properties as you select the object.

```
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:Entity}">
   <local:PropertyViewerTextBox Item="{Binding A1}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks for this snippet but its not clear for me how to use it. I added a new Class with this code. Then i did a new PropertyTextBox in my CodeBehind. I edited my DataTemplate but i never see a Textbox. Can you explain me more ?

Comment: That's not what the questioneer want's. Wasn't clear for me as well. But have a look at the comment under my question.

Comment: Well, I guess I didn't understand what he really wanted.